# Extract values from a varying parameters string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string like this, which I am getting after decrypting a key:

```
hardwareKey:12345,value1:1.1.1.1,value2:false,value3:410000,product:ABC
```

However, the string after decrypting for a different product will look like this:

```
hardwareKey:12345,value4:abcd-123,value5:100,value6:10000,value7:500,product:DEF
```

The Hardware Key will always be at the start and the Product will always be at the end.

All the value fields are different in the two strings. I tried to use a split, it worked but since I don't know which key I will get, it's a problem as each value has to be stored in a different variable in java, already defined in the file.

I tried something like this:

```
String parts[] = s.split(",");
System.out.println(parts[0]);
String p[] = parts[0].split(":");
System.out.println(p[0]);
```

With the following output:

```
hardwareKey:12345,value1:1.1.1.1,value2:false,value3:410000,product:MXK
hardwareKey:12345
hardwareKey
```

But in this approach, I have to take up every case which will take a lot of space and error prone. Can anyone help me with a better approach?

Comment: I think you can use an array of `value` and set array location depending upon `p[i].charAt(5)`

Comment: @RohanKumar can you show me how to do it. Total tunnel vision now.

Comment: I've added an answer showcasing my approach. Please review and provide feedback on whether it's helpful to what you're trying to achieve or not

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to convert the string into a map. Assuming you know what key maps to which variable in java

```
String s1 = "hardwareKey:12345,value1:1.1.1.1,value2:false,value3:410000,product:ABC";
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(s1.split(","))
                                   .map(s -> s.split(":"))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(ss -> ss[0], ss -> ss[1]));

String hardwareKey = result.get("hardwareKey");
String value1 = result.get("value1");
String product = result.get("product");

System.out.printf("HardwareKey:%s, value1:%s, product:%s", hardwareKey, value1, product);
```

Output:

```
HardwareKey:12345, value1:1.1.1.1, product:ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared a class for your decrypted key called `DecryptedKey`, it has three fields: `hardwareKey`, `values` and `product`(Note that `values` is an array of strings)

I declared a static `fromString()` method which handles converion of comma separated string to object. I'm just picking array index from 5th index of `value` string, then I'm assigning it to the respective array index.

```java
public static class DecryptedKey {
    private String hardwareKey;
    private String[] values;
    private String product;

    public DecryptedKey(String hardwareKey, String[] values, String product) {
        this.hardwareKey = hardwareKey;
        this.values = values;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public static DecryptedKey fromString(String key) {
        String[] parts = key.split(",");
        String[] values = new String[10];

        String hardwareKey = getValueFromEntry(parts[0]);
        String product = getValueFromEntry(parts[parts.length - 1]);
        for (int i = 1; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
            if (parts[i].startsWith("value")) {
                int index = parts[i].charAt(5) -'0';
                values[index] = getValueFromEntry(parts[i]);
            }
        }

        return new DecryptedKey(hardwareKey, values, product);
    }

    private static String getValueFromEntry(String keyAndEntryColonSeparated) {
        String[] parts = keyAndEntryColonSeparated.split(":");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            return parts[1];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hardware Key: " + this.hardwareKey);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Value " + i + " : "+ values[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Product: " + this.product);
    }
}
```

I tested it with this code:

```java
String input1 = "hardwareKey:12345,value1:1.1.1.1,value2:false,value3:410000,product:ABC";
String input2 = "hardwareKey:12345,value4:abcd-123,value5:100,value6:10000,value7:500,product:DEF";

DecryptedKey d1 = DecryptedKey.fromString(input1);
DecryptedKey d2 = DecryptedKey.fromString(input2);

d1.print();
d2.print();
```

This prints:

```
Hardware Key: 12345
Value 0 : null
Value 1 : 1.1.1.1
Value 2 : false
Value 3 : 410000
Value 4 : null
Value 5 : null
Value 6 : null
Value 7 : null
Value 8 : null
Value 9 : null
Product: ABC
Hardware Key: 12345
Value 0 : null
Value 1 : null
Value 2 : null
Value 3 : null
Value 4 : abcd-123
Value 5 : 100
Value 6 : 10000
Value 7 : 500
Value 8 : null
Value 9 : null
Product: DEF
```